# Why is webpack emitting font files that are actually javascript?

Tags: webpack, fonts, font-awesome

I'm trying to integrate `font-awesome` into a `webpack` project through `SASS`. However am running into a strange issue where the font files are being emitted like this:

*3cbb9abfb7d5d9b3ede7.woff*

```js
export default __webpack_public_path__ + "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff";
```

The referenced `fa-regular-400.woff` is also emitted at that location, however the emitted CSS references those weird javascript font files, which obviously aren't loaded by the browser as they are invalid.

The only reference to a similar issue I found was on this thread: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2680. However the solution there is specific to some other technology and not applicable in this case.

Here's the emitted directory:

[image]

So, here's my webpack rules:

```js
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/
}, {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
        }, {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run post css actions
        }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
        }
    ],
}, {
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
        loader: 'html-loader'
    }
}, {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?.*$|$)/,
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: "[path][name].[ext]"
        }
    }
}
```

And I import font-awesome like this in scss:

```css
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok well, strangely, the answer was removing the `file-loader` rule all together. I removed this section from webpack config:

```js
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?.*$|$)/,
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: "[path][name].[ext]"
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why the file loader is generating javascript pointers as "fonts" and images etc. Perhaps someone else knows.

Comment: Had the same issue and this solved it for me! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `file-loader` is [deprecated](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/), and Webpack recommends changing over to [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/).

Based on the recommended config on the `css-loader` [README](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#assets), you could replace your rule with this:

```js
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*$|$)/i,
    // More information here https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/
    type: "asset",
},
```

We were having the same problem and this seems to have fixed it.

---

As to why it broke:

- The `css-loader` [release notes for v6](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2021-07-14) say that they have deprecated use of `file-loader`, because `css-loader` will generate `new URL(...)` syntax by default and this by default uses `asset modules`.
- The [Asset Modules docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) indicate that if you are using it alongside the old loaders then you would need to "stop Asset Module from processing your assets again". I suspect that this means that the assets could be double-processed, which could lead to the file content as above.

I'm not 100% certain, but this seems like the most plausible explanation.